# how to get parent and child text for the kendo menu in the select event

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I am using kendo menu.For this I have parent level menu and for each I have sub items.
I want to get the parent item text and sub item text in the select event.

To get the parent text,I used "open" function,by this I am able to get parent text,but I want this in select event.

```
$("#menu").kendoMenu({
       open: function onOpen(e) {
              parentText = $(e.item).children(".k-link").text();
            },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have parent and child (two levels menu) you can use as selector for the parent the CSS class `k-state-active` This is a CSS class to add to each of the ancestors of the selected option.

Your code would be:

```
select: function (e) {
    var me = e.item;
    console.log("me", $(child).find(".k-link").text());
    var father = $(".k-state-active", this.element);
    console.log("father", father.text().trim());
}
```